# Map function is throwing errors in react js

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, javascript-objects, react-map-gl

I am new to React js and learnt developing static websites very quickly.
Since i was a huge fan of python i have developed my backend using Django-rest-framework.

i am successfully fetching my data from backend with react front end.

how ever i always like to work with functional components than state components.
i know i need to map my state object inorder to display contents in it but it is raising an error

```
TypeError: users.map is not a function
```

i don't know why and please guide me through this. one important thing is i am perfectly logging my data to console but not inside return().

the following is my code

```
import React,{useState,useEffect} from "react"
import{useHttpClient} from './components/http-hook'

const App=()=>{
  const[users,setuser]=useState({})
  const{isLoading,error,sendRequest,clearError}=useHttpClient()


  useEffect(() => {
    const fetchUsers=async()=>{
      try{
        const responseData=await sendRequest("http://127.0.0.1:8000/backend/list/")
        setuser(responseData)
      }
      catch(err){console.log(err)}
    }
   fetchUsers()
  }, [sendRequest])

  const fetchUserslist=async=>{
    console.log(users)
  }

    return(<div>
      <button onClick={fetchUserslist}>See list</button>
      <ul>
    {users.map(user=><div>{user.name}</div>)}
      </ul>
      </div>

    )
}

export default App
```

i have created my own custom hook useHttpClient to handle data and no complaints about it

Comment: change `const[users,setuser]=useState([])`

Comment: please tell me how to parse objects as well(if i have any use in future)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As i see

```
const[users, setuser]=useState({})
```

you have initiated users to a object it's not an array so when we try to `users.map` it will ended up with above error

to perform .map operation it has to be initialize to an array as below

```
const[users,setuser]=useState([])
```

---

if you really want to iterate through the object, the best thing you can do is get and array out of the object and loop it for ex:

```
const obj = {name: "hello", age: 23};

Object.keys(obj).map((key) => <div>{obj[key]}</div>)
```

Comment: thanks a lot it worked for me.. even tough its a small mistake i have confused.

Comment: may i know how to map objects,if i really want to work with objects

Comment: this is JS  specific, not react . BTW